# Concatenate and get all Column headers

Tags: python, pandas

I’d like to have a column name called SUBJECTS, before the one named STREAM.
Like this

```
SUBJECT  MEAN      RANK
ENG      59.2000      1
KIS      26.5474      3
MAT      56.6000      2
```

I’ve tried but this is the best I can get.

```
         SUBJECT    MEAN      
ENG      59.2000      1
KIS      26.5474      3
MAT      56.6000      2
```

I have this from a concatenation of

```
ENG       59.2000
KIS       26.5474
MAT       56.6000
```

And

```
ENG      1
KIS      3
MAT      2
```

```py
dfs = pd.concat([dfM, dfR], axis=1, sort=False,ignore_index=False,keys=[‘SUBJECT’,'MEAN', 'RANK'])
```

The two items picked from the “keys” is The first two,SUBJECT, MEAN, RANK is not recorded.

Your answer gets me to where I want to be only that RANK is NaN now.

```
    SUBJ     MEAN RANK
0    ENG  59.2000  NaN
1    KIS  26.5474  NaN
2    MAT  56.6000  NaN
```

Comment: which dataframe are you trying to concatenate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following :

1) Merge the two dataframes instead of concat

```
dfs = dfM.merge(dfR,how="left",on=0)
```

2) Rename the columns :

```
dfs.columns = ['SUBJECT','MEAN','RANK']
```

Should give you this

```
 SUBJECT     MEAN  RANK
 ENG       59.2000     1
 KIS       26.5474     3
 MAT       56.6000     2
```

Comment: Why is it returning an error?     return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'merge'

Comment: It means that 'dfR' and 'dfM' are series (probably columns of a dataframe). and not dataframes. Can you please show how youare getting 'dfR' and 'dfM'?

Comment: Please add the output of df.head() to your question, so I can get an idea of your dataframe

Comment: No, I meant display the initial dataframe from which you are extracting dfM and dfR.

Comment: dfM is the mean of the three subjects ENG,KIS and MAT thendfR is the ranks of dfM.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for this. It worked for me though I had to change the common column to 'index', rather than 0.
See below.

```
dfs = dfM.merge(dfR,how="left",on='index')
```